# inserting sql output rows to excel file

Tags: php, sql, excel

i have 150 rows and 40 columns in a sql table..i am displaying the entire table in a web page..now,what i want to do is create a link on that web page that will take the entire table and insert it in an excel file(dosn't matters if it creates a new excel file,or modifies sum exisiting one)...now i can do it manually by using(PHPExcel library)," objPHPExcel->setCellValue('C5', $v) "...but i would have to write this like 40 times(change '$v' variable in every statment) nd its inside a loop that will run 150 times..hence i dont wanna do it this way..

now i wanted to know if i can insert the table,row by row in the excel sheet..like when i insert a row,it will insert the entire cells of d row..that way it will be pretty easy..so i wanted to know if there any specific commands for doing this..

if not,wat other alternatives do i have of doing this..all i want to do is to export the entire sql table to an excel file using php..

Comment: try http://kevinjmcmahon.net/articles/24/exporting-mysql-table-data-to-excel-using-php/ or http://www.coderelic.com/2012/01/export-data-from-a-database-to-csv-excel-with-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So use the `fromArray()` method that PHPExcel thoughtfully provides that allows you to write a whole row or whole block of cells in one call from an array.

Looking at the examples and reading the documentation always helps

**Additional note**

Incidentally, `$objPHPExcel->setCellValue('C5', $v)` will only work if `$objPHPExcel` is a worksheet, most of the examples use $objPHPExcel for the **workbook** (ie the collection of worksheets) so don't get confused

**EDIT**

For fetching the results from your database, use

```
sqlsrv_fetch_array($tsql, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)
```

or

```
sqlsrv_fetch_array($tsql, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)
```

**EDIT 2**

Check how the database is set to handle NULL returns; but using

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($rows, 0, 'A'.$rowCNT);
```

should set all NULL values from the database result to 0 value in PHPExcel

Comment: here is what i am using..problem is its showing every value(value coming from database) twice in the excel sheet...and secondly some of the values are 0 in database,for all those values its shows an empty cell in excel... 

while($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $tsql ) )
{

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($rows, NULL, 'A'.$rowCNT);

    $rowCNT++;
}

Comment: Select your database query so that you don't return both enumerated and associative: one __or__ the other... that all comes down to how you're handling your database queries

Comment: As for the 0 values, first make sure you're getting a 0 back from the database query and not a NULL value

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to export a .csv file, which can also be read by excel.
All you have to do is create this page :

```
<?
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0"); 
$link = mysql_connect('db', 'dblogin', 'dbpasswd');
@mysql_select_db('dbname') or die( "Unable to select database");
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM whatever");
$j=0;
$nbField = mysql_num_fields($query);
while ($j < $nbField) {
    echo mysql_field_name($query,$j).";";
$j++;   
}
echo "\n";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM)) { echo implode(";", $row)."\n"; } 
?>
```

Then you insert a link pointing directly to this php page, it will download the csv file.